# How to increasingly change variable name inside a loop

Tags: javascript, variables, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to make a `for` loop that depending on the `objNumber` variable. It makes that many objects and names them with different variables, like so:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= objNumber; i++){
    var myElement = new Element('div', {id: 'slot'+i, class: 'slot'});
    var myObject+i = new myClass
}
```

I want to do this so that I can keep track of the names of all objects, and can reference them easily.

Each `myObject` will create another "child" object. If I keep all objects with the same number that way I can keep track of all the objects.

Is this the best way to do it? Or is it not possible?

Comment: You probably should use an array, but for future reference, you can use variable variables in javascript like so:
`var i = 'foo'; window[i+"bar"] = i; foobar == "foo"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use an array:

```
var myObjects = [];
for (var i = 1; i <= objNumber; i++){

        var myElement = new Element('div', {id: 'slot'+i, class: 'slot'});
        var myObjects[i] = new myClass
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the eval statement to do this, but a better approach is to use an associative array, where the key is the variable name. Doing it this way you can easily iterate over the objects you've created, and it creates more readable code.

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to use an array:

```
var myArray = new Array();
for (var i = 0; i < objNumber; i++){

        var myElement = new Element('div', {id: 'slot'+i, class: 'slot'});
        myArray.push(new myClass());

 }
```

Alternatively you could use the following:

```
 var myCollectionObj = {};
 for (var i = 1; i <= objNumber; i++){

        var myElement = new Element('div', {id: 'slot'+i, class: 'slot'});
        myCollectionObj["myObject"+i] = new myClass();

 }
```